# Text inside of a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an input that looks like this:
[image]

There are many different ways to approach making such an input, but I am trying to do it with as little javascript as possible.

The fill-ins for a gridded response look much like a radio button EXCEPT they have their labels on the inside of the button.  Unfortunately, the traditional radio button just won't do.

I'm looking for a way to imitate the look of a gridded response without using too much javascript/jquery/crazy css.  Any suggestions?

---

**Just to clarify:**

- I'm not looking for someone to code up the entire input.
- I know I need to use javascript/jquery/css, but I'm looking for something more elegant than a javascript/jquery only solution.
- **Cross browser compatibility is essential**

---

**Postmortem:**
I picked the answer that I did because it incorporated everything I wanted.  To readers of this answer, it doesn't work well in IE7.  I decided to go with sprites in the end, but position the label was a good idea and might work in IE8/9 (I'm on a mac and I don't have VMs for them at the moment)


Here is what I eventually did HTML/CSS wise.
Used the label as the selector and have JS change the background-color:

```
<div style=margin-bottom:5px;>
    <div style=float:left;>
        <input type=radio name=answer value=awesome id=answer style=display:none;>
    </div>
    <label style=float:left;background-color:red;background-image:url("/assets/images/radio_circle.png"); for=answer>
        <div style=width:20px;height:20px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;>
            1
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest, I can't think of a way to accomplish this without javascript/css, there's no real html facility for "text inside radio button."  Is there any particular reason for your aversion to jQuery (et. al)?

Comment: @ waffle paradox - I'm not against using javascript/jquery/css, I'm just looking for something more light weight than what I am thinking right now.

Comment: use css3 rounded corners to make a circle?

Comment: if you wrap text inside radio button, then how do u select that button??

Comment: @David Nguyen - how good is css3 with IE?

Comment: @diEcho - I want the text to be part of the button

Comment: actually it can't be done because you want it to behave like a radio button. pretty sure you will need javascript in order to do this

Comment: You can't change the size of a radio button (circle size) itself for all browsers, only the control width/height.  Standard HTML radio button look and feel are controlled by the OS.  So you'll need to make custom buttons that are circles, and then put them really close to each other.  When you click on one, you will need to use jQuery (or some JavaScript framework) to change the image on the custom image so it appears that it was clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably as good as it gets without going pretty much fully custom javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/MU95N/

Only css but you're very limited in what you can do.  You'd have to see how hard it is to make it cross-browser though, things may not line up right.

```
<input type="radio" name="one" id="one">
<label for="one">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="one" id="two">
<label for="two">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="one" id="three">
<label for="three">3</label>
<input type="radio" name="one" id="four">
<label for="four">4</label>
```

--

```
label{
    position: relative;
    left: -13px;  
    top: -3px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: That is pretty amazing.  Not 100% sexy looking as is, but with some tweaking I'm sure it could be almost exact.  I'm going to test it cross browser.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: why you don't use css sprite image as background?

Comment: @aSeptik - I was thinking about that, but I wanted to see if there was a more procedural way.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use css? Here's one that uses jQuery and CSS...

http://jsfiddle.net/TrowthePlow/dGxAN/2/

Comment: @afuzzyllama: Gotcha...unfortunately, not many browsers support styling radio buttons. See http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a preset style of button(being a radio button I'm pretty sure the OS or browser sets the default size when coded with html) I'm pretty sure you won't be able to put text inside of a radio button using html and css working in conjunction. That said I went looking for buttons that would do what you want. Naturally Google and such returned a lot of results to do it via various methods but all involved a programming languages other than html and css alone.

[The best thing I found was this jQuery and Css button styling system.](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/) JQuery will accomplish what you want out of the buttons and the css will leave you with the ability to give them a nice custom look.

The full code as to how to create the frame work for the buttons is on the page, naturally you'll have to modify it get it to be the way you want, but this will hopefully get you started.